# TYPESCRIPT : Argument of type 'typeof X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Y' with extends

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, extends

I am starting to code with typescript and I have a few compilation problems.

I have several classes and it seems that I have a hierarchy problem

On my first class (A) I indicated a set of properties / functions. I have a second class (B) which inherits from class (A) and which adds certain properties / functions. Finally I have a third class (C) which inherits from the second 
class (B).

```js
export default class A {
    prop1: string;
    function1() {
        console.log('TEST');
    }
}

export default class B extends A {
    prop2: string;
    function2() {
        console.log('TEST');
    }
}

export default class C extends B {
    prop3: string;
    function3() {
        console.log('TEST');
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error message :

> TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof C' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'A'.    Type 'typeof C' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'B': prop1, function1.

My 3 classes are in 3 separate files and I use export / import and it seems to work ...

Do you have an idea?

TSCONFING:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a code like this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=75&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEIFtIB2wBMAQusHAN4BQc9cYUEYAXHGjFAJYEDmAbhp1EEApygBXBDGgAKJi1YTefAJTUR9GAAtuaAHSKwcALyNmYIfQC%20NOzVCRYiVBmx5CxeKBjEAJpg4%20GLe5GiUtAxwELrAUAAKluwq-EJaouJc0rJQCskcXKoANDFxiQWp6prR0WiSYPH5LGrWtdp6hrE68UksZmU9FSxtdg5O0PDI6JikkjCyBADixPHcCHC%20AUGeoSQ1DABG84t9bIU8acLRCGISOfLHC2JnKUX8GlHtHA1NAOTGP6lP7dXqWP6tDLRXT6AxPU6WAbwl6WNq2ezCCYuabuObPAgAZUaCG4ADN1psQH4CIE4HjFisiDwNl96MjCcTXhdVOkbndsjJHicxETgAguVVPlCGPVGnk-uyzhDpR1YezReLEeZ1ZzURkxsJMeBJq4Zh4QkQSAAxFCCqAAT00IigwD4%20j8Lv8ABV7Y00KwALIoMAAHiqpWCXhI4WAAD5rpl7na5FLoZ0DC63Zx4sBvb7gJhzEQAO5wIOh8PmqNkCixlOjBOZ91NHFoAByKFwwGU7z4pVbOCyUjtrEjexrEVTDDJcDkAEIYYYm9nPT6-QYdOg5K2O121FO07Dlx7c2uCwYIjBt25253gP2b4Ok7lIdE7OiRAgXSg-NeZrvu0rYx4hgbgCx7S5qlZOAZ3nRcM1dZtV3zQxNzQP8MAA-cDjTZhSwAUSgZh5S9HpTXcABtP44AAanI28u1ouA-gAXTgfwIALAgAB0-h8EB3UMDxJCQfweL4xBvz8OASxiQ4ACsxRgCE0TgBxoiQYApkfflh1yAZ4OPHM83XPgtIwhjgDUYoVRgrIUAIBBKCLYBSwHXSHjyYDYDAtBXwYF0YEkKACDszgHKchsMRoW4sjgG07XtekxCfeBzAVYUCD%20dIsW0s1koIBLckdLYaR2C1vCK6BHWg2Ln3kA9allJp-PaQzEJXOQqodArUtKAqNTJdZWrUhN6C-YAf2AAbiSGhA5B1MUJV7RrokC4LQvgiapq621it6-lSkWzUWlUsYgA). The error messages that sound on the site are not quite the same as I have in my editor, but maybe when correcting on the site I will find the final problem ...

Thank you so much.

Comment: What version of the TS are you using? Post please tsconfig file.

Comment: In the playground I see only one issue - multiple default exports

Comment: Here is my tsconfig file :

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}

Comment: It still works fine. Is this is actual code? Seems you have duplicated property inside the child like partner: ```name:string``` and child: ```name:number```;

Comment: You can use typescript playground to check your code

Comment: I added a link in my post (at the end) to add an example closer to the final code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the playground link, it helped to find the issue.

It was not working because you want to store a factory, asked for an instance.

The main trick is here:

```js
registeredTypes: Map<string,typeof ComponentBase>
```

The full fixed version is here:

```js
export class ComponentBase {
  prop: string;

  constructor(prop: string) {
    this.prop = prop;
  }
}

export class Component extends ComponentBase {
  otherProp: string;

  constructor(prop: string, otherProp: string) {
    super(prop);
    this.otherProp = otherProp;
  }
}

export class ButtonGeneric extends Component {
  buttonProp: string;

  constructor(buttonProp: string) {
    super('prop', 'otherProp');
    this.buttonProp = buttonProp;
  }
}

export class ButtonSpecific extends ButtonGeneric {
  buttonSpecProp: string;

  constructor(buttonSpecProp: string) {
    super('buttonProp')
    this.buttonSpecProp = buttonSpecProp;
  }
}



export class ComponentFactory {

  registeredTypes: Map<string,typeof ComponentBase>

  constructor() {
    this.registeredTypes = new Map<string,typeof ComponentBase>();
  }

  register(className: string, classConstructor: typeof ComponentBase) {
    if (!this.registeredTypes.has(className)) {
      this.registeredTypes.set(className, classConstructor);
    }
  }

  create(className: string, properties: string) {
    if (!this.registeredTypes.has(className)) {
      throw Error('The class [' + className + '] doesn\'t exists. Couldn\'t create new object');
    }

    let classConstructor = this.registeredTypes.get(className);
    if (classConstructor == null) { throw new Error('') }
    const instance = new classConstructor(properties);
    return instance;
  }

}

const FactoryButtonConst = 'button';

export class ButtonFactory extends ComponentFactory {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.register(FactoryButtonConst, ButtonSpecific);
  }

  createButtonSpecific(buttonSpecProp: string) {
    return this.create(FactoryButtonConst, buttonSpecProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. In the meantime I had tried otherwise but it allows me to better understand typescript. I took your code and it works great.

Comment: I don't know if I can still take advantage of your kindness, I just posted a new subject ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989342/typescript-material-design-webpack-cannot-find-module-material-base-and-gen