# TYPESCRIPT/Material Design/Webpack : Cannot find module '@material/base' and Generic type 'MDCComponent<FoundationType>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, material-design, node-modules

I have a new problem. I try to use material design (materiel.io) with Typescript and Webpack.
First, I installed material with npm.
Then, in one of my classes, I import @material/base.

```
'use strict';
import {MDCComponent} from '@material/base';
export default class Component {
  MDCComponent: MDCComponent;
  constructor() {
    this.MDCComponent = undefined;
  }
}
```

In my editor, I already have the following message:

> Cannot find module '@material/base'.ts(2307)

For information, I use visual studio code editor, with eslint. Here is my eslintrc.json configuration file:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017,
    "sourceType": "module"   },   "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true   },   "globals": {},   "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],   "rules": {
    "array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "never", {}],
    "brace-style": "error",
    "camelcase": ["error", { "properties": "never" }],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "never",
        "objects": "never",
        "imports": "never",
        "exports": "never",
        "functions": "never"
      }
    ],
    "comma-spacing": ["error", { "before": false, "after": true }],
    "comma-style": ["error", "last"],
    "complexity": ["warn", 7],
    "computed-property-spacing": ["error", "never"],
    "curly": ["error", "all"],
    "dot-notation": ["error", { "allowPattern": "^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)+$" }],
    "eol-last": "error",
    "eqeqeq": ["error", "always"],
    "for-direction": "off",
    "func-call-spacing": ["error", "never"],
    "indent": [
      "error",
      2,
      {
        "ArrayExpression": "first",
        "CallExpression": { "arguments": "first" },
        "flatTernaryExpressions": false,
        "MemberExpression": 1,
        "ObjectExpression": "first",
        "outerIIFEBody": 0,
        "SwitchCase": 1,
        "VariableDeclarator": { "var": 2, "let": 2, "const": 3 }
      }
    ],
    "key-spacing": ["error", { "beforeColon": false, "afterColon": true }],
    "keyword-spacing": ["error"],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "max-depth": ["error", 3],
    "multiline-comment-style": ["error", "starred-block"],
    "no-caller": "error",
    "no-cond-assign": ["error", "except-parens"],
    "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
    "no-empty": "error",
    "no-loop-func": "error",
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "error",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { "max": 1 }],
    "no-multi-str": "error",
    "no-new": "error",
    "no-self-assign": ["error", { "props": false }],
    "no-sequences": "error",
    "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
    "no-undef": "error",
    "no-unreachable": "error",
    "no-unsafe-negation": "error",
    "no-unused-expressions": ["error", { "allowShortCircuit": true }],
    //"no-unused-vars": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-with": "error",
    "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
    "one-var": [
      "error",
      { "var": "always", "let": "consecutive", "const": "never" }
    ],
    "one-var-declaration-per-line": ["error", "initializations"],
    "operator-linebreak": ["error", "after"],
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "semi-spacing": ["error", { "before": false, "after": true }],
    "semi-style": ["error", "last"],
    "space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
    "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "never"],
    "space-in-parens": ["error", "never"],
    "space-infix-ops": "error",
    "space-unary-ops": ["error", { "words": true, "nonwords": false }],
    "wrap-iife": ["error", "inside", { "functionPrototypeMethods": true }]   } }
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
   }
 }
```

Then when compiling my file, I get the following error message:

> TS2314: Generic type 'MDCComponent' requires 1 type
>   argument(s).

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=dev ./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "hotdev": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=dev ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --hot --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "extract-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.3",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "material-components-web": "^5.1.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

What should I do ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: 1. Restart VsCode to get rid of the first error
2. Check the definition of the MDCComponent. It is require something to be passed into

Comment: I restarted VsCode, but I still get the error message. For the second, I can't find the expected type. I will try to find.

Comment: What exact package did you install?

Comment: I add my package.json in the post. From this base class, I will make a class for each component (MDCComponent) of material design to make a template system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. In my tsconfig.json file, I must add **moduleResolution** flag with **node** value, in compilerOptions : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html